# Jquery UI close button layout issues

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I am currently working on a project that uses Jquery UI 1.8.10 and it's been that way for a while without issue however it seems that the "X" on the close button in the dialogs has suddenly developed layout issues, it pushed down and to the right. I was able to fix it by editing the CSS file jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css, I removed the 50% positioning on the top and left. The CSS now looks like the code below.

```
.ui-button-icon-only .ui-icon, .ui-button-text-icon-primary .ui-icon, .ui-button-text-icon-secondary .ui-icon, .ui-button-text-icons .ui-icon, .ui-button-icons-only .ui-icon 
{ position: absolute; top: 0%; margin-top: -8px; }
.ui-button-icon-only .ui-icon { left: 0%; margin-left: -8px; }
```

What I don't understand is what changed? No one has edited the CSS file until I did and I can't find anything that would have caused this issue elsewhere in the code. Does anyone have any idea what happened? I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather tell you to put the "X" in a separate div so that it wouldn't hurt the layout.

Here is the piece of code I wrote for my layout:

Demo Here:

[https://jsfiddle.net/VijayVj7/5yqg9mdo/]

Hope it helps you

```
 <div >
      <span id="close">&#10006</span>
 </div>
```